# Have multiple ranges with different attributes on NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I have a multiline UILabel of which I would like to increase the line height, but I also want part of it to be a different color, only the line height works fine. But as soon as I try to change the color for a certain range it just goes back to the stock appearance, no line either..

Anyone a tip? This is done in the content setter.

```
- (void)setContent:(NSString *)content {
    _content = content;

    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.content];
    NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttrString = [attributedString mutableCopy];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    [paragraphStyle setLineSpacing: 5.0f];

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                                 NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"BentonSans-Regular" size:16.0],
                                 NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle
                                };
    NSDictionary *colorAttributes = @{
                   NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]
                   };
    [mutableAttrString addAttributes:attributes range:NSRangeFromString(self.content)];
    [mutableAttrString addAttributes:colorAttributes range:NSMakeRange(4, 8)];


    [self.label setAttributedText: mutableAttrString];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: is your setter method called ?

Comment: @DheerajSingh correct!

Comment: so is it working correctly now.

Comment: @DheerajSingh no not yet, line hight is working correctly but all text is black..

Comment: go through my posted answer and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your viewdidLoad Method assign string to self.content :

```
self.content = @"pass your text ";
```

// Remove the First line of your method it is not needed

```
- (void)setContent:(NSString *)content {

    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.content];
    NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttrString = [attributedString mutableCopy];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    [paragraphStyle setLineSpacing: 5.0f];

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                                 NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"BentonSans-Regular" size:16.0],
                                 NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle
                                };
    NSDictionary *colorAttributes = @{
                   NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]
                   };
    [mutableAttrString addAttributes:attributes range:NSRangeFromString(self.content)];
    [mutableAttrString addAttributes:colorAttributes range:NSMakeRange(4, 8)];


    [self.label setAttributedText: mutableAttrString];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `NSRangeFromString` function expects a string like `@"{3,10}"`. In other words, it expects a string that contains two numbers that specify the starting location and length of the range. I suspect that the `content` string isn't a string like that.

So this line

```
[mutableAttrString addAttributes:attributes range:NSRangeFromString(self.content)];
```

should be

```
[mutableAttrString addAttributes:attributes range:NSMakeRange(0,mutableAttrString.length)];
```

Comment: Okay that brings back my line height, but my colorAttributes don't seem to work yet... All text is black

Comment: Not sure why that would be, it worked for me. I tested with a multi-line label, and using the string's `drawAtPoint` method.